# Can you explain to me this Powershell SQL command?

Tags: sql, powershell

Please help me fully understand this code below; I grasp the SQL CommandText but all the commandlets (I think that's what they're called) such as .CommandOut, .FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors, .add_InfoMessage, etc. is what I don't understand. Is there a page/doc that helps me understand what their functions are? This Powershell script works, but I don't truly get it, I get small fractions of whats going on and would like to fully grasp what I ripped off the interwebs lol. TIA!

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "Server = <server here> ;Database = <database here>;Integrated Security = SSPI;";
$global:msg = ""
$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {
    param($sender, $event) 
    $global:msg = $event.Message
    Write-Host $global:msg
};
$conn.add_InfoMessage($handler);
$conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true
$conn.Open();
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand();
$cmd.CommandTimeout=0
$cmd.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = '$variable') `
Print 'This is just a placeholder message'";
$res = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$conn.Close();
```

I understand the SQL CommandText but all the commandlets (I think thats what they're called) such as .CommandOut, .FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors, .add_InfoMessage, etc. is what I don't understand. Is there a page/doc that helps me understand what their functions are? This Powershell script works, but I don't truly get it, I get small fractions of whats going on and would like to fully grasp what I ripped off the interwebs lol. TIA!

Comment: This PowerShell code is manipulating .NET objects directly: other than `New-Object` there are no other cmdlets being used in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the Microsoft website should help.
Here's the link for the .FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.fireinfomessageeventonusererrors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0